# Remapping a specific key in a specific input layout only

Tags: macos, keyboard

I have a MacBook with a physical EN-US keyboard that I use with EN-US and TR-Q input layouts daily. I'm quite shocked that there is no way to input a quotation mark `"` using just a regular keypress on a physical EN-US keyboard with the TR-Q input layout. The closest thing you can get is `"` using the combination <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ğ</kbd> (<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> on the US layout), and even that is a weird sideways quotation mark that appears quite funky and is simply not-gonna-work when coding/scripting.

*Aside: Why is it even possible to type in that symbol when it is not possible to type in a simple quotation mark?*

My question is: Is there a way to do either one of the following on macOS, without having to install a program?

- Modify a key's behavior ***only in one** of the input layouts.*
- Prepare and add a custom input layout.

*Aside: I've been using this "US keyboard, US/TRQ layout" setup for 7 years now on Windows without any issues. I'm quite surprised that the macOS maps the TR-Q input layout differently, and in a way that is quite unusable.*

Answer (score 0):

The standard quote mark " is on the key just below escape on an ISO keyboard as used in Europe.  But I guess you are using the US ANSI version, which is missing one key, and unfortunately it is that chracter.  You can use [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/) to fix this.

In general, you can use [Keyboard Viewer](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-the-keyboard-viewer-on-mac-mchlp1015/13.0/mac/13.0) to find which key does what.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to the particular case described is using the **Text Replacements** functionality. (You don't need to read the rest of this answer if you already know what it is.)

---

Here's a brief tutorial on how:

1. Go to **Settings > Keyboard > Text Input > Text Replacements...**
2. Hit the **+** sign
3. Replace `”` (type in with <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ğ</kbd> in the TR-Q input layout)
4. With `"` (type in with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> in the EN-US input layout)

You can then use the key combination <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ğ</kbd> to type `"` in the TR-Q input layout on a physical EN-US keyboard, without having to switch back and forth between input layouts.

The replacement seems to happen after:

1. Typing anything right after the `”` symbol.
2. Typing in a space right after the first "word" (any sequence of symbols made out of non-space characters) that comes after the `”` symbol. There may or may not be a space before this word, it doesn't matter.

So if you still want to be able to type in the `”` symbol and keep it from time to time, you can do so by putting it in between an existing text and then not doing any one of the two above.

Comment: This whole answer is typed in using the TR-Q input layout on a physical EN-US keyboard. The `"` that is produced by the replacement also gets replaced for a second time (by the ways of the secondary replacement event, also described in this answer) into the directional quotation marks in the apps that have that feature (e.g., Mail). So, this seems to fix the case described thoroughly. Still, it doesn't exactly fulfill the requests in the question, and thus, it is perhaps not fit for being the accepted answer.